# Problem in trying to push to a page from a child of a ListView.builder (Flutter BLoC)

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-navigation

In a page of my app I have a ListView that shows data from Firestore, fetched through various BLoCs. These blocs are all provided at the top of the widget tree, right above MaterialApp. So the children of the ListView get access to the blocs, but each one of them has a button that does `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(*newPageRoute*)`. This new page also should have access to the blocs, isn't it?

Know that routing works through onGenerateRoute.

I've tried to provide the blocs by doing

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) {
      return BlocProvider.value(
        value: BlocProvider.of<
            ComplexQueryBloc>(context),
        child: BlocProvider.value(
          value: BlocProvider.of<
              UserQueryBloc>(context),
          child: BlocProvider.value(
            value: BlocProvider.of<
                FieldQueryBloc>(context),
            child: PastGamePage(
                booking: widget.booking),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Let me know if you need to know something else. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://It%20is%20used%20as%20a%20dependency%20injection%20(DI)%20widget%20so%20that%20a%20single%20instance%20of%20a%20Bloc%20or%20Cubit%20can%20be%20provided%20to%20multiple%20widgets%20within%20a%20subtree.) of `BlocProvider`:

> It is used as a dependency injection (DI) widget so that a single
> instance of a Bloc or Cubit can be provided to multiple widgets within
> a subtree.

This is from the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html) of `BlocBuilder`:

> If the bloc parameter is omitted, BlocBuilder will automatically
> perform a lookup using BlocProvider and the current BuildContext.

This essentially means, that no new bloc is created by the `BlocBuilder` if the `bloc` parameter is omitted and the bloc created by the `BlocProvider` will be used.

Btw, you can use `MultiBlocProvider` to simplify the code.

Comment: I thought about it, but by doing that i'll have a different instance of the blocs. Will I have access to the state of the blocs of the ancestor blocs?

Comment: @AntonioLentini If you wrap your BlocProvider on above Material Page then you can access from anywhere. As well if you give Bloc to parent then child can easily access that bloc and change based on parent state also.